# Why isn't the HTML on the page being updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The website: http://mercury.demomycms.co.uk/account.php (register account tab).

I am creating an AJAX Handler so I can have one single AJAX JavaScript file for my website, and then pass all AJAX calls through it.

All is working well so far, it can send the AJAX request to the right file and receive the data back in JSON format, however I have an issue when it comes to updating the HTML on the page.

I am passing back a variable with the `ID` of the object to place the HTML in.

I am also passing back another variable with the HTML to put in that object. I get back all the data from the AJAX call fine. However it will not update the HTML on the page at all.

**This is my code:**

```
/**
 * $value contains an array of the following
 *
 * content      The HTML code that is replacing the content of the specified div.
 * fade         Whether to fade out the ID or not before changing the content.
 * fadeOut      Whether to fade out the div after a certain amount of time.
 * function     Function to call at the end of the case.
 * restore      Restore the original content in the div. Only used if fadeOut is set.
 * targetId     The ID of the target div that is having it's content replaced.
 */                  
case 'html':
    console.log(value);
    var $target = $('#' + value.targetId);
    var original = '';
    if(value.restore) original = $target.html();
    if($target.length > 0) {
        if(value.fade) {
            $target.fadeOut(500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $target.html(value.content).fadeIn(500);
            }, 510)
        } else {
            $target.html(value.content);
        }
    }
    if(value.fadeOut > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $target.fadeOut(500);
        }, value.fadeOut);
    }
    if(value.fadeOut > 0 && value.restore) {
        $target.html(original);
    }
    if(value.function != false) {
        window[value.function]();
    }
    break;
```

`console.log(value)` produces the expected, it gives me the correct `ID` and HTML, and if I do `console.log($target)`, then I get the jQuery object back with a length of 1.

The `fadeOut` is working fine, so I know I can manipulate `$target` fine, so why can I not replace the HTML?

I have created a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/styphon/7TtwH/), and it works.

So why wouldn't it work in my AJAX?

---

**UPDATE**

After @nrabinowitz comment I removed all code apart from just updating the HTML and it worked. This code works:

```
case 'html':
    console.log(value);
    var $target = $('#' + value.targetId);
    $target.html(value.content);
    break;
```

What could potentially cause it to stop working in an if else statement?

---

**UPDATE 2**

After taking the case apart and putting it back together again (using undo, not copy and paste or anything, just undoing deletes) it works. The code is the same as I originally posted, and it suddenly works >.< ... Go figure. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log()` to the timeout handler?

Comment: No errors on the console. And I hand't tried adding a console.log to the timeout handler, but I did add one to the else part and I did get to the else as expected.

Comment: If you have an issue with ajax, maybe you should show your ajax code too... My take is that you are not waiting for the ajax call to complete.

Comment: If the fiddle works with this code, then this code isn't the problem, and you're looking in the wrong place. In my experience this kind of thing usually involves some async process you aren't fully dealing with.

Comment: @Christophe that can't be the issue because this is in the success part of the Ajax call and I hit all other parts of this function, including the fade out. The **only** part that doesn't work is the HTML update. I can run console.log to see the response from the Ajax call, and all the information is there as expected.

Comment: and what about console.log(value.content) - value outputted expected - but does this?

Comment: @nrabinowitz You're right. After your comment I stripped it back to just updating the HTML, doing nothing else, and it works. But again, why would the whole thing work in the fiddle and not in my code? Also, what could possibly stop it from working? I guess I need to break it down bit by bit.

Comment: @jave.web yes, it gives me the HTML code I am expecting to be outputted to the page.

Comment: @Styphon you really need to do a `console.log()` of `value.content` *inside* the timeout handler. It's possible that some other code is clearing out `value.content` before the timeout handler can run.

Comment: And what is the EXACT output of console.log($target) ?

Comment: @Pointy I have, and it's exactly what I expect to be outputted, however I'm not running inside the timeout at the moment, I'm just trying to work in the else part that doesn't even use that timeout for now.

Comment: If `value.fade` is `false` and `value.fadeOut` is non-zero and `value.restore` is `true` then your code resets the content back to the original value *after* it updates it to the new value.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's its purpose, but fadeOut will be around 5000, so the message displays and then it fades out and the original content is restored, ready to pop open again.

Comment: Very strangely it is now working... original answer updated...

Comment: It was probably some sort of caching issue. Make sure to turn of your browsers cache while developing, it will save you a lot of headaches.